# How to configure django-uploadify for videos upload only?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to use [django-uploadify](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify) to upload for videos only, I just want it to upload videos only, all kind of videos, or at least all kind of popular video formats.

So far, i added `uploadify` in `settings.py` and in `urls.py` I added this

`(r'^uploadify/',include('uploadify.urls')),`

But didn't go through every step described in the [docs](https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/wiki) just yet, I'll do the other steps when you tell me how to configure django-uploadify for videos only.

django-uploadify is not well documented so i'm relying on your experience to configure it.

if you have a better way to create a video uploading form, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-uploadify does not come with a custom filefield you are still going to use the django FileField that AFAIK does not have this kind of validation (filename extension checking).

You have to implement yourself this validation, you can do that using model validation or you can extend the django-uploadify form and add some validation there.

you can see a code example [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/977/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the templatetag to include the [fileExt](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/) option to enable client side file extension checking. This will only check if someone is "probably" uploading a video.

You should of course also implement server side model validation too, as you can't trust the client.