# Django-crispy upload forms

Tags: python, django, django-1.3

Yesterday I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960099/how-to-configure-django-uploadify-for-videos-upload-only/9964167#9964167).

I then found this snippet:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from app.extra import ContentTypeRestrictedFileField

class upload(models.Model):
    """ upload """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(
        upload_to='/media/videos,'
        content_types=['video/avi', 'video/mp4', 'video/3gp', 'video/wmp', 'video/flv', 'video/mov'],
        max_upload_size=104857600
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('modified', auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**form.py**

```
from django.db.models import FileField
from django.forms import forms
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ContentTypeRestrictedFileField(FileField):
    """
    Same as FileField, but you can specify:
        * content_types - list containing allowed content_types. Example: ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg']
        * max_upload_size - a number indicating the maximum file size allowed for upload.
            2.5MB - 2621440
            5MB - 5242880
            10MB - 10485760
            20MB - 20971520
            50MB - 5242880
            100MB 104857600
            250MB - 214958080
            500MB - 429916160
    """
    def __init__(self, content_types=None,max_upload_size=104857600, **kwargs):
        self.content_types = kwargs.pop('video/avi', 'video/mp4', 'video/3gp', 'video/wmp', 'video/flv', 'video/mov')
        self.max_upload_size = max_upload_size

        super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        data = super(ContentTypeRestrictedFileField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

        file = data.file
        try:
            content_type = file.content_type
            if content_type in self.content_types:
                if file._size > self.max_upload_size:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(self.max_upload_size), filesizeformat(file._size)))
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Filetype not supported.'))
        except AttributeError:
            pass        

        return data

        from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
        add_introspection_rules([], ["^app\.extra\.ContentTypeRestrictedFileField"])
```

and add this line is **settings.py**

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 157286400 # 157286400 bytes = 150 MB
```

---

I just found out about an app called [Django-crispy forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms). They give you [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/1838193) to create [this form](https://camo.githubapp.com/182a9b1c4fc34f43b2c986dd6ed554ed793f5905/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4c535245672e706e67)

**My question is:**

Is it possible to combine my snippet with django-crispy to create a form which looks like this? I know that I have to use [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See what css selector django is giving the form. Then use your style sheet to change its appearance. You can even set the selector yourself see docs for more info.